# using order by and group by together in mysql

Tags: mysql

there is table called sample with columns name and games.

```
name      games  
a        tennis  
b        tennis  
c        football  
d        shuttle  
e        basketball  
f        football  
g        football
```

and so on.

I need the list of fisrt 2 most played game and first 2 least played game.
how to use group by and order by together?

Comment: where is column for number of people playing

Comment: why is that needed? we need to count the number of times each game played(may be using group by) and then we need to use order by.but i have no idea how to use them together. @NirpendraPatel

Comment: how will u query for most played game

Comment: @NirpendraPatel for each person there is a new entry in the data table I guess.

Comment: I think You can not select both in one query most and least played.

Comment: we can do that by using union. @HarshSanghani

Comment: for that you have to union two select query, and its not one select....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a count ordered you can do this

```
select count(*)  as num, games from sample 
group by games 
order by  num
```

for the firts two

```
select count(*)   as num, games from sample 
group by games 
order by  num limit 2
```

for the last  two

```
select count(*)  as num, games from sample 
group by games 
order by  num DESC limit 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select games, count(1) value
from sample
group by games order by value desc limit 2
UNION ALL
select games, count(1) value
from sample
group by games order by value limit 2
```